# Can my server handle 12,000 database requests per-minute?

Tags: mysql, php, performance, database

First of all, Apologies if this is a silly question. I've never really had to manage servers and databases, on a "large-scale", that is.

ANYWAY, on to the question. I am trying to figure out if our current server can handle 12,000 database requests per minute. (once again, I don't know if this a lot. I assume it's mid-range). I am estimating that 2/3 of the 12,000 requests will be simple `SELECT` queries from super small tables. No more than 20,000 rows in a table-  I've made a point to prune them on a regular basis. LAMP Stack.

**Below are the server hardware and software specs:**

Processors- Intel Haswell 2095.050 MHz

Memory -  7.45gb useable

Storage - 80GB SSD

OS- Ubuntu, CentOS 7

**DB**

MySQL

V5.7.25

PHP - 7.2.7

The database is stored on the same server as where files are being served.

If this server is capable of this, how much further can the server be pushed?

Thank you in advance (And sorry if this seems to be a dumb question)

Comment: Run a test against it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there's a lot that goes into it. If it's being combined with the web server, you need to consider factors like how many web requests to your web server do you anticipate and what impact will that have on I/O and RAM? Are you going to limit the number of processes Apache can spawn? How much memory will each child process use? How large is your database datafiles? How large of a Buffer pool are you going to create? And most importantly of all, are your queries optimized?

Too many variables for us to give an exact answer. Though as Zoredache said, the only way you'll really know is to test it.